# How to get a value to call a function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to get a value return to run a call function in Excel

Sub ID_Num is what i want to call on in the first ws.range of Sub SubmitButton, but i cannot work out how to call a function, so i have tried pulling in the code from the function as shown below. This works once and adds a number but after that it stops - something to do with the ActiveCell.Row part

```
ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "=MAX(A2:A" + CStr(ActiveCell.Row - 1) + ")+1"    'Adds the ID into Col A & Last Blank Row"
```

My current code is:

```
Sub ID_Num()

 Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data")

ActiveCell.Formula = "=MAX(A1:A" + CStr(ActiveCell.Row - 1) + ")+1"

ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Value 'Convert formula to a value

End Sub



Sub SubmitButton()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "=MAX(A2:A" + CStr(ActiveCell.Row - 1) + ")+1"    'Adds the ID into Col A & Last Blank Row"
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username") 'Adds the UserName into Col B & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") 'Adds the Date_Time into Col C & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C5") 'Adds the Name into Col D & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C7") 'Adds the Service into Col E & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("F7") 'Adds the Team into Col F & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C9") 'Adds the Cycle into Col G & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("F5") 'Adds the Date into Col H & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C11") 'Adds the Section into Col I & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C13") 'Adds the Functionality into Col J & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C15") 'Adds the Form into Col K & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C17") 'Adds the Report into Col L & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("C19") 'Adds the System1_ID into Col M & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("F19") 'Adds the System2_ID into Col N & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Form").Range("B22") 'Adds the Comment into Col O & Last Blank Row


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What cell are you referring to with `ActiveCell`?  Why don't you just point to it directly with `Range("Ax")` or `Cells(x,x)`?

Comment: The ActiveCell is the Cell it currently is in as it is having multiple entries added at any given point. So as it is using the LastRow feature wouldnt know which cell to go up to. So A2:ALastRow ID it is adding it for.

Comment: `ws.Range("A" & LastRow)` refers to a cell in the last row.  What does `CStr(ActiveCell.Row - 1)` refer to?  Do you mean to write `CStr(LastRow - 1)`

Comment: Thanks Sorry, not thinking straight that worked, i am sure i had tried it.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!  I've reposted my comment as an answer, if you could accept it, it'd help me a bunch.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `CStr(ActiveCell.Row - 1)` with `CStr(LastRow - 1)`